# Audit logging of various user operations in multiple microservices

Tags: microservices, audit-logging

I have 7 micro-services and web-app to access REST calls. I want to log the operations user performing for any backend call. I am thinking to implement audit-log micro-service which has just one DB table and just one RESTful operation. Every time user performs any operation, that micro-service will call RESTFul API of audit-log.

Do you think this approach is better or is there  any other best practices or solution?

I implemented micro-service.

I am using java 8, JPA, Spring Framework, POSTGRESQL

I expect good design and good practice to follow in my code.